# This page includes a password or credit card input in a non-secure context

Tags: web-application, http

I am in doubt whether this is a programming or security issue.
I have noticed that Google Chrome is sending this message in the console:

> This page includes a password or credit card in a non-secure context.

However, my app's hosting provider is selling the HTTPS service as a separate service.

Currently I am not able to purchase this service.
So what should I do to resolve this situation by avoiding future problems?

Maybe an alternative would be to use [CryptoJS](https://code.google.com/archive/p/crypto-js/)?

Comment: So, to clarify, you have written an application that has passwords or credit card data but you do not pay for HTTPS?

Comment: What's your question? Are you asking for a secure alternative to https to submit credit card numbers to your app? If so,  that's nothing short of reckless. Or are you transmitting passwords in an insecure way?

Comment: It's just a login and password, no credit card transaction, I just put the message that appeared to me

Comment: Even still, sending passwords over HTTP is a terrible idea. If you can install your own certs, use something like LetsEncrypt, or buy yourself a $5 cert somewhere like ssls.com. Do not put your customer's privacy in jeopardy because you skimmped out on an SSL cert.

Comment: @iain, yes, transmitting passwords in an insecure way

Comment: @Matt Clark, I'm seeing about LetsEncrypt, it seems to me to be good

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Currently I am not able to purchase this service. So what should I do to resolve this situation by avoiding future problems?

It's pretty simple: use https. Chrome has detected that you're passing around private information on an unsecured channel, and is rightfully telling you that that's a major security issue.

There are many options for purchasing a TLS (SSL) certificate, including the monetarily free Lets Encrypt, but this isn't a forum for service recommendations. What really matters is that you get one.